# How to re-load UIView after memory unload?

Tags: iphone, memory, uikit, uiview, uiviewcontroller

My main view controller (representing the Main Menu in my app) has a simple UIView with a few sub views. I am using a modal-type design pattern and switch to multiple other view controllers before finally returning to the main menu. The problem is, in my other view controllers (not the main menu one), I often load data-heavy images and the like which sometimes causes the main menu (which is not currently on-screen) to unload its view to in response to memory warnings. The problem is, when I ultimately switch back to my main menu, the screen is all black and all but a few UILabels have been dispensed of. At this point, I would like to re-load my view and start fresh. But in the documentation, it says that you should never call -loadView directly. How can I re-load my view?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this situation, check the `isViewLoaded` property — it should be returning `NO`. If the view has been unloaded correctly, `isViewLoaded` will return `NO` and calling `view` on your view controller will automatically load in the view again.

Check your custom view unloading code — you should be removing everything from the view hierarchy (`[[self view] removeFromSuperview]`) that belongs to you.

If you haven't got any unloading code, make sure you're not over-retaining some of your views, which will cause problems when unloading.